# Is there a module for Rails in puppet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puppet

http://forge.puppetlabs.com - Is there a module for deploying Rails using puppet on a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a module to deploy rails using puppet, something like following:
/puppet/modules/rails/init.pp

```
class rails {
$package = ["rails"]

package { $package:
       ensure => installed,
}

}
```

/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
node * {
      include rails
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers @deep. Can you also point me to the relevant docs in puppet which helps with rails installation.

Comment: you dont need any documentation for installation of rails, you just need to know the package-name which the package manager software installs. So in your case apt-get installs rails by package-name: "rails"